# How to aggregate using in clause in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

My MongoDB collection looks like:

```js
{
  "url" : "a1",
  "user" : "b1",
  "time" : ISODate("2017-12-25T00:45:22.148Z")
}
{
  "url" : "a2",
  "user" : "b2",
  "time" : ISODate("2017-12-24T22:45:22.148Z")
}
{
  "url" : "a3",
  "user" : "b1",
  "time" : ISODate("2017-12-24T21:45:22.148Z")
}
.....
```

I want aggregate urls for a given user but only the last N most recent urls for that user.

Suppose a user most recent visited url are: url1, url2, url3, ...ect
If N=2, then I want to count only url1, url2 for all users.

I would like to build a query similar to this pseudo SQL:

```
select url, sum(url)
from mycollection
where url in (select top N url from mycollection where user=user1)
group by url
```

Comment: Aggregate with a `$match` stage, followed by a `$sort` stage, followed by a `$limit` stage.

Comment: I have already an descending index on the field time, I don't need to sort. But with query, I will just get the most recent urls. What I need along side with each url is the total number in the whole collection for ALL USERS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [non-correlated](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#uncorrelated-subquery) sub query from 3.6 for your use case.

Something like

```
db.mycollection.aggregate(
 [{$lookup:{
   from: "mycollection",
   pipeline:[
    {$match:{"user":user1}},
    {$sort:{"time":-1}},
    {$project:{"url":1}},
    {$limit:n}
   ],
   as: "topn"
 }},
 {$match:{
   $expr:{
     $in:[
      "$url",
      "$topn.url"
    ]
  }
 }},
 {$group: {
  _id: "$url",
  count: {$sum:1}
 }}
)
```

[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html) to pull in the "url" for input user followed by [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html) to filter the documents where "url" is in list of urls.

[`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort) and [`$limit`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit) to top n.

[`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html) allows use of aggregation comparison operators in $match stage.

[`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/index.html) to compare the url against list of urls.

[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group) to group the url and count occurrences.

Comment: Thanks.  The first part of the query Lookup does not return n documents, it is doing a Cartesian product I think

Comment: Np.Sorry there is trailing space in collection name. Fixed now.

Comment: It is working now, thanks :) However my query is slow, I have 2 indexes: (url, user, time), (user, time) but still the explain gives me a COLLSCAN, I don't know which index is missing

Comment: Np. Well I'm sure lookup in its simple form can take advantage of indexes for equality comparison. Not sure if the new lookup variation ( with pipeline ) are optimized to use indexes.

Comment: I've found the [jira](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-31760) fixed in 3.7.1 ( dev version). Can you update and see if it works ?